# Converting Java Set to an argument for PreparedStatement setString method

Tags: java, jdbc, set

What would be the simplest way to covert a `Set<String>` to an argument for Oracle `in (?)`? I am already using PreparedStatement for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The query must have one placeholder (`?`) for each of the elements in the set. And you have to bind every element of the set:

If your set has three elements, your prepared statement must look like this :

```
String sql = "select foo.* from FOO foo where foo.id in (?, ?, ?)";
```

and you must iterate through the set and bind each element individually:

```
int i = 1;
for (String s : setOfStrings) {
    statement.setString(i, s);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, basically I mean how to covert a Java Set = {1,2,3} into a Java String = "'1','2','3'". I know how to do it but I was just wondering if there is an API method to do that.

Comment: My point is that it won't help. You can't bind this string ("'1', '2', '3'") as one single parameter of the prepared statement.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't. It probably generates the following SQL: where foo.id in ('''1'', ''2'', ''3'''). See http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2

Comment: Hey JB Nizet, you certainly are correct, it does not work, I was using PS but without using setString method. I wonder why does it not work, does it look for commas to separate bind variables?

Comment: It does not work because setString binds one parameter of type String. And "'1', '2', '3'" is a String. It thus binds the parameter to this String, and simply escapes the apostrophe characters in this String.

Comment: Nizet, so when you say escapes apostrophe, do you mean to say when the query runs it will have foo.id as \'1\',\'2\','\3\'?

Comment: Nope, as '''1'', ''2'', ''3'''. In SQL, an apostrophe is escaped by prepending another apostrophe (i.e. by doubling the apostrophe).